# insert dailymotion channel (not video) in html frame

Tags: html, frame, channel

I'm very new to all this IT stuff so I will ask a question that may seem very obvious and noob to you, still, I'd appreciate some help.

I have a very basic html only website built with frames, I want a friend's Dailymotion channel to be displayed in one of those frames, mind that I want the channel and not some particular video, the channel address is something like 'http://www.dailymotion.com/channelname/' and I only find instructions for displaying specific videos.

Can anyone help me with this very basic problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can using the below code.

```
<frame src="http://www.dailymotion.com/channelname/">
```

You can learn more about [frames at W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frame.asp)

Comment: I have tried that, and a direct link to it, opening in new window, opening in another frame inside same frameset... I've tried everyway I know about establishing a link. Not working. Page does not load, no data being transmitted from dailymotion. Could it be some specific code for dailymotion or that they do not allow link to channels, only videos?

Comment: Probably they have blocked their site for loading into frames, as they have SDK/APIs for developers.